# Getting expected end of statement error in VBScript while editing XML tag

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a XML file where there are many `<itemDateValue>` tags. I just want to change the value for first 2 of these tags. Following is what I tried for this, but getting 'expected end of statement' error.

```vb
Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("itemDateValue")[1]
objNodeList.Text = nextDateFunc(x) & "T00:00:00Z"
```

I can do this for all tags with a `For Each` statement but I need only for 2 tags.
Also I tried with semicolon at the end (since I saw an example somewhere) but didn't help.

Also let me know if there is any better approach.

Comment: [Reference 1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.02.heyscriptingguy.aspx). [Reference 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx)

Comment: `GetElementsByTagName("itemDateValue")[1]` is giving you an error because the VBScript index operator is `()`, not `[]`. A better approach is usually working with `SelectNodes` and [XPath expressions](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html). You'd need to provide more information about your code, input XML and desired result for an answer, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with different approach than using `GetElementsByTagName`. Following is what I did and worked as per my requirement:

```vb
Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//itemDate/itemDateValue")

For j = 0 To 1
    objNodeList(j).Text = nextDateFunc(x) & "T00:00:00Z"
Next
```